# Выгрузить данные из Датафрейма Pandas в Эксель сложной конфигурации

Tags: python, xml, pandas, openpyxl

Всем здравствуйте! Я инженер, пытаюсь немного облегчить себе жизнь автоматизацией расчетов теплоизоляционных конструкции для трубопроводов и арматуры. Данные подаются в программу с двух excel спецификаций, одна для трубопроводов , другая для арматуры. Сохраняется соответственно в 2 разных датафрейма. После подсчётов необходимо выгрузить в общую ведомость (формат excel или word, тут можно выбирать). Формат ведомости достаточно сложный, не все ячейки надо заполнять и во всех строках, при этом группировка там идёт по кодам трубопроводов: трубопровод, потом арматура с тем же кодом если есть, если нет - следующий код и т.д.
Не понимаю как это лучше реализовать, openpyxl записывает , но неудобно это получается, непонятно как учесть разрывы страниц. Картинку ведомости прилагаю. Может стоит создать шаблон XML и вот уже его заполнять? Спасибо!

[image: Шаблон жёлтым цветом выделены ячейки, необходимые для заполнения]

UPD. Не сразу разобрался как подгружать файлы. [Пример датафрейма](https://wdfiles.ru/9268f7)

Comment: во-первых, неплохо бы прилагать пример датафрейма. во-вторых, мне кажется, что каждый пункт ведомости на картинке (первый и второй) - записывается в одну строку, если не считать переноса длинных строк. то есть, структура не такая уж сложная.

Comment: Я не говорю, что это рокетсайнс, но это не просто выдача где все строки подряд заполнены, здесь не так , просто циклом пробежаться результата не дало.